# Composing sync and async functions in Swift 5.5

Tags: swift, async-await

Consider the following (silly) example:

```
func u () async -> UInt32 {
    let r =  UInt32(Int.random(in: 1...10))
    sleep(r)
    return r
}

func v(_ x: UInt32) -> UInt32 {
    x
}

Task.init{
    print(v(await u()))
    print(await v(u()))
    await print(v(u()))
}
```

All three lines in the task appear to work. Are they equivalent, or are there any pitfalls I should be aware of? Thanks.

Comment: Note: don't use `sleep` in an async function, this blocks the executor from doing other work while sleeping. Use `Task.sleep` instead. `Task.sleep` can also respond instantly to cancellations - `sleep` cannot.

Comment: Thanks, but this is just of the sake of example.  I'm not really using the code anywhere, nor do I intend to. The question is about positioning of the await keyword in each of the three lines of the task. Sleep() is immaterial; I could just as well take it out.

Comment: Just as a note for any future readers!

Comment: Point taken. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like `try`, Swift allows you to place the `await` keyword on any part of an expression that contains an `async` method:

```swift
func ƒ<T>(_ v: T) -> T { v }


// All equivalent:
func somethingThatThrows() throws {}
print(ƒ(try somethingThatThrows()))
print(try ƒ(somethingThatThrows()))
try print(ƒ(somethingThatThrows()))


// All equivalent:
func someAsyncFunc() async {}
Task {
    print(ƒ(await someAsyncFunc()))
    print(await ƒ(someAsyncFunc()))
    await print(ƒ(someAsyncFunc()))
}
```

The [Swift grammar reference for the `await` keyword](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Expressions.html#ID646) does have an example for where placement of `await` does matter (`await`ing only a subexpression of a whole expression that needs to be `await`ed), but it's not quite relevant here:

```swift
// await applies to both function calls
sum = await someAsyncFunction() + anotherAsyncFunction()

// await applies to both function calls
sum = await (someAsyncFunction() + anotherAsyncFunction())

// Error: await applies only to the first function call
sum = (await someAsyncFunction()) + anotherAsyncFunction()
```

Comment: While not part of the answer, I will say that idiomatically, it's more common to leave `await` as a keyword on the outermost part of the expression, to indicate that the whole thing `await`s — unless you have a very complex expression and want to very clearly indicate which part of the expression is `async`. (You just have to be a bit careful with the latter, lest the `await` keyword be made more difficult to find...)